# How to show app UI to accept and reject video calls and prevent conflict with other on going apps?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, telecommunication

I am working in an android app where user accept or reject video call which is working fine. but now i want to prevent app conflict with others if we have any other call like what's app or skype.

I have then read [self managed connectionservice](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged.html) and try to implement it.

[Here is complete doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html)

From Activity i first register

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
                    new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MyConService.class),
                    "example");

        PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "example")
                    .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED).build();
        tm.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);

    }
```

Then try to add new call by doing something like below:

```
PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
                    new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MyConService.class),
                    "example");
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL, "11223344", null);
extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_ADDRESS, uri);
tm.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, extras);
```

App is always crashed on tm.[addNewIncomingCall](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#addNewIncomingCall(android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle,%20android.os.Bundle))(phoneAccountHandle, extras) with following log

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.liverep.videochat, PID: 27754
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liverep.videochat/com.liverep.videochat.VideoChat}: java.lang.SecurityException: This PhoneAccountHandle is not enabled for this user!
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: This PhoneAccountHandle is not enabled for this user!
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
at com.android.internal.telecom.ITelecomService$Stub$Proxy.addNewIncomingCall(ITelecomService.java:1450)
at android.telecom.TelecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(TelecomManager.java:1225)
at com.liverep.videochat.VideoChat.placeIncomingCall(VideoChat.java:792)
at com.liverep.videochat.VideoChat.call(VideoChat.java:730)
at com.liverep.videochat.VideoChat.registerForPhoneCall(VideoChat.java:716)
at com.liverep.videochat.VideoChat.onCreate(VideoChat.java:133)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Hey,  just a question; did you had to use SIP to make your video calls?

Comment: Not compulsory to use SIP

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have [MANAGE_OWN_CALLS](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/Manifest.permission.html#MANAGE_OWN_CALLS%3Akotlin.String) permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Register your PhoneAccount properly then use `addNewIncomingCall()`. In my case it worked.

```java
telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount1);
telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(myPhoneAccountHandle,bundle);
```